# Reading data after adding into table return zero

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, transactions, hql

I have a problem when I add several rows into talbe in transaction
and read that data from table.
I have tested data before I adding, to prevent duplicated data.
My table have no autogenerated index.
Since I enabled hibernate to show sql I saw that insert into table 
executed after my reading data, so I have got wrong data.

```
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
```

I know that I could flush session before reading, but that is not good solution for me, becouse if my program create exception, data were stored 
into table, and I will have a problem.

My table was converted into INNODB engine 
          ALTER TABLE mytable ENGINE=InnoDB;

Here is my project

I removed import from files
**AppInitializer.java**

```
package rs.co.master.config.web;
 import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;
 @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "rs.co" })
 public class AppInitializer  extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer
 implements WebApplicationInitializer{
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { ApplicationContextConfig.class };
    }
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
     @Override
     public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    appContext.register(ApplicationContextConfig.class);
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet(
            "test", new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
    dispatcher.setInitParameter("display-name", "test");
    dispatcher.setInitParameter("Version", "dec");
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");
}
 }
```

**ApplicationContextConfig**

```
 package rs.co.master.config.web;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.Locale;
 @Configuration
 @EnableWebMvc
 @MultipartConfig
 @EnableAspectJAutoProxy
 @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "rs.co" })
 public class ApplicationContextConfig  extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
     @Autowired
      ConfigurationForTiles configurationForTiles;
        @Override
        public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
            InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
            viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
            viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
            viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
            registry.viewResolver(viewResolver);
        }
        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/themes/**").addResourceLocations("/themes/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
            registry.addResourceHandler("/ui/**").addResourceLocations("/ui/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
            registry.addResourceHandler("*.jpg").addResourceLocations("").setCachePeriod(31556926);
        }

        @Override
        public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer matcher) {
            matcher.setUseRegisteredSuffixPatternMatch(true);
        }
        @Bean
        public MessageSource messageSource() {
            ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
            messageSource.setBasename("messages");
            messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
            return messageSource;
        }
        @Bean
        public LiteDeviceResolver liteDeviceResolver() {
            List<String> keywords = new ArrayList<String>();
            keywords.add("iphone");
            keywords.add("android");
            return new LiteDeviceResolver(keywords);
        }

        @Bean
        public DeviceResolverHandlerInterceptor deviceResolverHandlerInterceptor() {
            return new DeviceResolverHandlerInterceptor(liteDeviceResolver());
        }

        @Override
        public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
            registry.addInterceptor(deviceResolverHandlerInterceptor());
            registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
        }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        CookieLocaleResolver resolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("sr_LATN_RS"));
        resolver.setCookieName("localeCookie");
        resolver.setCookieMaxAge(4800);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("locale");
        return localeChangeInterceptor;
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionLocaleResolver sessionLocaleResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("sr", "sr_LATN_RS"));
        return localeResolver;
    }


    @Bean(name = "supportedMediaTypes")
    public ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter supportedMediaTypes() {
        ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter supportedMediaTypes = new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter();
        List<MediaType> suppMedType = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
        suppMedType.add(MediaType.IMAGE_GIF);
        suppMedType.add(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
        suppMedType.add(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG);
        suppMedType.add(MediaType.ALL);

        supportedMediaTypes.setSupportedMediaTypes(suppMedType);
        return supportedMediaTypes;
    }
```

**ConfigurationForTiles.java**

```
 package rs.co.master.config.web;

 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
 @Configuration
 public class ConfigurationForTiles {
     @Bean
     public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {
         final TilesConfigurer configurer = new TilesConfigurer();
         configurer.setDefinitions(new String[] { 
                "/WEB-INF/config/tiles.xml"
                });
         configurer.setCheckRefresh(true);
         return configurer;
     }
     @Bean
     public TilesViewResolver tilesViewResolver() {
         final TilesViewResolver resolver = new TilesViewResolver();
         resolver.setViewClass(TilesView.class);
         return resolver;
     }
 }
```

**HibernateConfiguration.java**

```
 package rs.co.master.config.web;
 @Configuration
 @EnableTransactionManagement
 @ComponentScan({ "rs.co" })
 @PropertySource(value = { "classpath:database.properties" })
 public class HibernateConfiguration {
     @Autowired
     private Environment environment;
     @Bean
     public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
         LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
         sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
         sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "rs.co" });
         sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
         return sessionFactory;
      }

     @Bean
     public DataSource dataSource() {
         DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
         dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("database.driver"));
         dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("database.url"));
         dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("database.user"));
         dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("database.password"));
        return dataSource;
     }

     private Properties hibernateProperties() {
         Properties properties = new Properties();
         properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
         properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
         properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
         properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
         properties.put("hibernate.connection.useUnicode", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.connection.useUnicode"));
         properties.put("hibernate.connection.characterEncoding", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.connection.characterEncoding"));
         properties.put("hibernate.connection.charSet", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.connection.charSet"));
         return properties;        
     }

    @Bean
     @Autowired
     public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
        return txManager;
     }
 }
```

**IndexController.java**

```
 package rs.co.webController;
 @Controller
 @RequestMapping("")
 public class IndexController {
    private static final Logger logger = 
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(IndexController.class);
    @Autowired
    private DataService dataService;
    @RequestMapping(value = {"", "/"}, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
    public @ResponseBody
    ModelAndView index(
            Locale locale, 
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");
        model.addObject("welcome", "werew rew");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/fillData", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
    public @ResponseBody
    ModelAndView fillData(
            Locale locale, 
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");
        Random number = new Random();
        Integer x = number.nextInt(100)+1;
        if (x < 0) x = x * - 1;
            try{    
                 Integer result = dataService.fillData(x);
                 model.addObject("resultSum", result);
        }
         catch (Exception e) {
             logger.error("Error {}.", e.getMessage());
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         finally {
         }  
        return model;
    }
 }
```

**DataModel.java**

```
 package rs.co.webModel;
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "mytable")
 public class DataModel implements Serializable {
    @Id
    // @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "idtable")
    private Integer idtable;
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "number")
    private Integer number;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -729870310313L;
    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }
    public DataModel() {
        super();
    }
    public DataModel(Integer idtable, Integer number) {
        super();
        this.idtable = idtable;
        this.number = number;
    }
    public void updateModel(DataModel inModel) {
        this.idtable = inModel.getIdtable();
        this.number = inModel.getNumber();

    }
 }
```

**DataService.java**

**DataServiceImpl.java**

```
 package rs.co.webService;
 @Service("DataService")
 @Transactional
 public class DataServiceImpl implements DataService{

    @Autowired
    DataDao dataDao;

 // @Override
    public Integer fillData(Integer number) throws Exception {
        return dataDao.fillData(number);
    }   
 }
```

**DataDao.java**

**DataDaoImp.java**

```
 package rs.co.webDao;
 import rs.co.webModel.DataModel;

 @Repository("DataDao")
 @Transactional
 public class DataDaoImpl  implements DataDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public Integer fillData(Integer number) throws Exception{
        Session sess = sessionFactory.openSession();
         Transaction tx = null;
            try{    
                 tx = sess.beginTransaction();
                    emptyTable();
                     for(int i = 0; i < number; i++){
                            Random n = new Random();
                            Integer x = n.nextInt(100)+1;
                         DataModel dm = new DataModel(i+1, x);
                         addData(dm);
                     }

            tx.commit(); 
        }
         catch (Exception e) {

             if (tx!=null && tx.getLocalStatus() != LocalStatus.ROLLED_BACK) 
                    tx.rollback();
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         finally {
             sess.close();
         }  
         Integer sumNumbers = getSumNumber();
         return sumNumbers;
    }
    @Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public DataModel getData(Integer idtable) {
        DataModel tmp = null;
        Query query;
        String sql = 
                  " from DataModel t"
                + " where idtable = :idtable "
            ;
            query = sessionFactory
                    .getCurrentSession().createQuery(sql);
            tmp = (DataModel) 
                        query
                        .setInteger("idtable", idtable)
                        .uniqueResult();
        return tmp;
    }
    @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void emptyTable() throws Exception {
        sessionFactory
        .getCurrentSession()
        .createQuery(
                "DELETE FROM DataModel t"
                    )
                    .executeUpdate();       
    }
    @Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    private Integer getSumNumber() {
        Long tmp = null;
        Query query;
        String sql = " select COALESCE(sum(t.number), 0) as number"
                + " from DataModel t";
            query = sessionFactory
                    .getCurrentSession().createQuery(sql);
            tmp = (Long) query.uniqueResult();
        if (null == tmp) return 0;
        return tmp.intValue();
    }
    @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public DataModel addData(DataModel inModel) throws Exception {
        DataModel model = null;
        model = getData( inModel.getIdtable());
        if (null == model){
            model = inModel;
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(model);
        } else {
            model.updateModel(inModel);
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(model);
        }
        return model;
    }
    @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void deleteData(Integer idtable) throws Exception{
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(
                        "DELETE FROM DataModel "
                                + " where idtable = :idtable ")
                .setInteger("idtable", idtable).executeUpdate();
    }
 }
```

**Resource database.properties**

```
          database.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
          database.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test??characterEncoding=UTF-8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&characterEncoding=UTF-8&characterSetResults=UTF-8
          database.user=test
          database.password=test
          hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
          hibernate.format_sql=true
          hibernate.show_sql=true
          hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
          hibernate.connection.useUnicode=true
          hibernate.connection.characterEncoding=UTF-8
          hibernate.connection.charSet=UTF-8
```

**tiles.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"
        "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">

 <tiles-definitions>
     <definition name="base.definition" template="/WEB-INF/tiles-templates/mainTemplate.jsp">
         <put-attribute name="title" value="test"></put-attribute>
         <put-attribute name="header" value=""></put-attribute>
         <put-attribute name="menu" value=""></put-attribute>
         <put-attribute name="body" value=""></put-attribute>
         <put-attribute name="footer" value=""></put-attribute>
     </definition>
```

**mainTemplate.jsp**

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
 <%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
 <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
 <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
 <%@ taglib prefix="security" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
 <c:import url="/WEB-INF/tiles-templates/homeHead.jsp"></c:import>  
 <body>

 <div id="main">

    <div id="header" >
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="header"></tiles:insertAttribute>
    </div>
    <div id="main1">
        <div id="menu1">
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="menu"></tiles:insertAttribute>
        </div>
        <div id="middle">
            <div id="b1">
                <tiles:insertAttribute name="body"></tiles:insertAttribute>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer"></tiles:insertAttribute>
    </div>

 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**homeHead.jsp**

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
 <%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
 <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
 <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
 <%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"  %>
 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html lang="sr_RS">
 <head>
  <%@ page isELIgnored="false" %> 
   <meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
   <meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>

 <title>
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="title" ignore="true"></tiles:insertAttribute>
 </title>
 </head>
     <definition name="index" extends="base.definition">
         <put-attribute name="title" value="test"></put-attribute>
         <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp"></put-attribute>
     </definition>
 </tiles-definitions>
```

**index.jsp**

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
 <%@ taglib prefix="tiles" uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles"%>
 <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
 <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
 <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
 <%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
 <%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 <!--
 function fillData(){
    window.open("/test/fillData"
        ,
        "_self");
     ;
  }
 //-->
 </script>
 <h2>Hello World!</h2>
 <input type = "button" value="Click me" onclick="fillData()">Click to fill data and sum
 <br>
  <c:if test="${resultSum > 0 }">
      Result = ${resultSum }
  </c:if> 
  Result = <c:out value="${resultSum }"/>
```

Comment: That is a mountain of code and not a very good description of a specific problem. Try and post the **minimum** required to demonstrate your issue, not everything you have.

Comment: My method public Integer fillData(Integer number) throws Exception return 0, but in mytable I have data with sum > 0

Comment: `Integer x = number.nextInt(100)+1; if (x < 0) x = x * - 1;` x cannot be negative and even if it could, `Math.abs()` is better than this *-1. For the rest, I know you found a solution but you needed to explain what you were trying to do in your writing part and reading part because we have better things to do than figure out your heap of code and guess your intentions.

Comment: Yes. My mistace. Random number is between 0 and 1

Answer (score 0):

I resolve problem 
In main controller I open new Session and transaction.
In DataImplementation I getCurrent session and open transaction in the same session

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/fillData", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
public @ResponseBody
ModelAndView fillData(
        Locale locale, 
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){


    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");
    Random number = new Random();
    Integer x = number.nextInt(3)+1;
    if (x < 0) x = x * - 1;
    Session sess = sessionFactory.openSession();
     Transaction tx = null;
        try{    
             tx = sess.beginTransaction();
             Integer result = dataService.fillData(x);
             model.addObject("resultSum", result);

        tx.commit(); 
    }
     catch (Exception e) {

         if (tx!=null && tx.getLocalStatus() != LocalStatus.ROLLED_BACK) 
                tx.rollback();
         logger.error("Error {}.", e.getMessage());
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     finally {
         sess.close();
     }  

    return model;
}
```

**do not close session in dao implementation. It will be closed in controller**

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public Integer fillData(Integer number) throws Exception{
    Session sess = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Integer sumNumbers = -1;
     Transaction tx = null;
        try{    
             tx = sess.beginTransaction();
                emptyTable();
                 for(int i = 0; i < number; i++){
                        Random n = new Random();
                        Integer x = n.nextInt(100)+1;
                     DataModel dm = new DataModel(i+1, x);
                     addData(dm);
                 }
                 sumNumbers = getSumNumber();

        tx.commit(); 
    }
     catch (Exception e) {

         if (tx!=null && tx.getLocalStatus() != LocalStatus.ROLLED_BACK) 
                tx.rollback();
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     finally {
 //will be closed in controller          sess.close();
     }  
     return sumNumbers;
}
```